# Modifying Watched LESS Variables in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using bootstrap that defines many less variables, take`@body-bg` as an example. I created a color theme that defines `@background`. To glue the two together I do the following:

```css
@body-bg: @background
```

Now, I want to be able to switch between color themes. So I use less' watch feature to change `@background`, but less doesn't appear to propagate this to the @body-bg and it actually switches to the bootstrap default.

I don't want to do either of the following

- `less.modifyVars({ '@body-bg': '#FFFF00' })`
- `less.modifyVars({ '@background': '#FFFF00', '@body-bg': '@background' })`

because there are many other variables that are defined from `@background`.

Here are some test pages.

**Problem.htm**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="problem.less" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.4.1/less.min.js#!watch" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="less.modifyVars({ '@background': '#FF0000' })">Apple Style!</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="less.modifyVars({ '@background': '#FFFF00' })">Banana Style!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**problem.less**

```css
@background: #FF0000;
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@body-bg: @background;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that if `less.env` is set to `production` the imported files get cached in a weird way and don't get loaded after you call `less.modifyVars()` see here:

**https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/721#issuecomment-11611703**

So setting the environment to `development` seems to fix the problem:

### [DEMO](http://newtpond.com/test/less1.html)

Modified markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/problem.less" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
    less = { env: "development" };
   </script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.4.1/less.min.js#!watch" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="less.modifyVars({ '@background': '#FF0000' })">Apple Style!</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="less.modifyVars({ '@background': '#FFFF00' })">Banana Style!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great answer and your demo works, but when I replace import "problem2.less" with import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less" the example no longer works. So, setting the env doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: now the demo in my answer imports bootstrap ... it takes a bit longer to compile to css but it seems to work for me just the same.

Comment: Did you comment out `@body-bg: #fff;` in bootstrap/less/variables.less?

Comment: yes, sorry ... I just checked ... I did comment out `@body-bg` in `variables.less` so that the variable you set wouldn't get overwritten.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, if you comment out `@body-bg` in `variables.less` you do not have to use `less = { env: "development" };`